# Extracting multiple substring from a string

Tags: python, regex, replace

I have a complicated string and would like to try to extract multiple substring from it.

The string consists of a set of items, separated by commas. Each item has an identifier (id-n) for a pair of words inside which is enclosed by brackets. I want to get only the word inside the bracket which has a number attached to its end (e.g. 'This-1'). The number actually indicates the position of how the words should be arrannged after extraction.

```
#Example of how the individual items would look like
id1(attr1, is-2) #The number 2 here indicates word 'is' should be in position 2
id2(attr2, This-1) #The number 1 here indicates word 'This' should be in position 1
id3(attr3, an-3) #The number 3 here indicates word 'an' should be in position 3
id4(attr4, example-4) #The number 4 here indicates word 'example' should be in position 4
id5(attr5, example-4) #This is a duplicate of the word 'example'

#Example of string - this is how the string with the items looks like
string = "id1(attr1, is-1), id2(attr2, This-2), id3(attr3, an-3), id4(attr4, example-4), id5(atttr5, example-4)"

#This is how the result should look after extraction
result = 'This is an example'
```

Is there an easier way to do this? Regex doesn't work for me.

Comment: I can't make sense of your example. Could you try describing it a different way?

Comment: @DaoWen - Sorry the string itself is a little complicated. It's difficult to describe it.

Comment: What governs the reordering of items?

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams - the number attached to the end of the second word in the brackets.

Comment: What happened to the other example?

Comment: @BurhanKhalid - I edited some of the post for clarity.

Comment: I think `This-2` means `This` should be in position 2, but it's at the front of your _result_ string. How does that work?

Comment: How close is the example to the real data? If possible, can you post a piece of real data?

Comment: If that's the case, then your result should be `'is This an example example'`, but that's not what you have shown.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A trivial/naive approach:

```
>>> z = [x.split(',')[1].strip().strip(')') for x in s.split('),')]
>>> d = defaultdict(list)
>>> for i in z:
...    b = i.split('-')
...    d[b[1]].append(b[0])
...
>>> ' '.join(' '.join(d[t]) for t in sorted(d.keys(), key=int))
'is This an example example'
```

You have duplicated positions for `example` in your sample string, which is why `example` is repeated in the code.

However, your sample is not matching your requirements either - but this results is as per your description. Words arranged as per their position indicators.

Now, if you want to get rid of duplicates:

```
>>> ' '.join(e for t in sorted(d.keys(), key=int) for e in set(d[t]))
'is This an example'
```

Comment: `example` is repeated, though, which is not what OP wants.

Comment: well if you want to be technical, his example isn't actually what he wants either since the words are switched around.

Comment: I would take that as a typo. But the requirement about same position is stated quite clearly, though.

Answer (score 2):

Why not regex? This works.

```
In [44]: s = "id1(attr1, is-2), id2(attr2, This-1), id3(attr3, an-3), id4(attr4, example-4), id5(atttr5, example-4)"

In [45]: z = [(m.group(2), m.group(1)) for m in re.finditer(r'(\w+)-(\d+)\)', s)]

In [46]: [x for y, x in sorted(set(z))]
Out[46]: ['This', 'is', 'an', 'example']
```

Comment: You failed to detect that `example` is repeated (same position of 4) and only one of them should be kept.

Comment: OK, I have revised borrowing ``set`` from Burahn's answer.

Answer (score 1):

OK, how about this:

```
sample = "id1(attr1, is-2), id2(attr2, This-1), 
          id3(attr3, an-3), id4(attr4, example-4), id5(atttr5, example-4)"


def make_cryssie_happy(s):
    words = {} # we will use this dict later
    ll = s.split(',')[1::2]
    # we only want items like This-1, an-3, etc.

    for item in ll:
        tt = item.replace(')','').lstrip()
        (word, pos) = tt.split('-')
        words[pos] = word
        # there can only be one word at a particular position
        # using a dict with the numbers as positions keys 
        # is an alternative to using sets

    res = [words[i] for i in sorted(words)]
    # sort the keys, dicts are unsorted!
    # create a list of the values of the dict in sorted order

    return ' '.join(res)
    # return a nice string


print make_cryssie_happy(sample)
```